# Identifying third party cookies with request headers in JavaScript and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, frontend

If while loading a website, I capture all the request headers (let's say in chrome dev tool), and then I find that few of the request headers host have a domain different from the current website domain and they also have a cookie attached.

Will it be correct to conclude that the website uses third party cookies?